# Electric panel radiator won't turn on but it is warm where the gauge is

Tags: electrical-panel, radiator

I have bought this house from 78 and it has nobö electric panel radiators 400V. I tried to turn them on for the first time but they won't turn on. The interesting thing is they are a bit warm where the temperature gauge is. What could be wrong with them?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without the manual I can't tell but my guess is the green tab sets the turn on temperature and the red stop is the turn off temperature.

Set the green up to 25°C and see what happens. Set the red where you want it to shut off.

Comment: I cannot find the manual. It is from the 70ties. I played with both red/green but nothing happens. I tried another radiator in the same plug and that works fine. So, I have 4 non-working and 1 working. It is so strange though, non working ones get hot by the temperature gauge but radiator itself is not. Makes me think if the thermostat could be broken which takes down the radiator with it.

Comment: Radiator is Nobö Electro 400V - Type PER 04 407 if anyone can find the manual.